# CloudFlare access.log not updating

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, proxy, log

I recently set up my home server to use CloudFlare (Ubuntu Server 16.04.1).  Everything seems to work fine and it's awesome.

However, I have a major problem, every time I check my `access.log` in Apache I realize that CloudFlare logs are simply not showing up there or updating.  If I connect directly to my IP address, the access.log is updated immediately but if I access my site through the CloudFlare domain then the `access.log` file doesn't update at all.

I'm really confused as I don't understand how this is possible, I thought all CloudFlare does is change the incoming IP, why would it stop my server from logging it?

***Edit:*** If it helps I also got a bunch of these logs added to my `access.log` file, no idea if they are related or not:

```
::1 - - [12/Dec/2016:13:37:26 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [12/Dec/2016:13:37:27 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [12/Dec/2016:13:37:28 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main potential issues here:

1. You're hitting a cached resource, which isn't reaching your origin server. If you've set a ["Cache Everything" Page Rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256-How-do-I-cache-static-HTML-), Cloudflare will also cache static HTML. The CF-Cache-Status header indicates [whether Cloudflare is caching a resource](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168266-What-do-the-various-CloudFlare-cache-responses-HIT-Expired-etc-mean-).
2. You're not recording visitor IPs correctly. On Apache, you should be sure to [install the Mod_Cloudflare extension](https://www.cloudflare.com/technical-resources/#mod_cloudflare) to ensure you are recording visitor IPs correctly in your logs.

Comment: Starting from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Cloudflare no longer updates and supports `mod_cloudflare`.

Answer (score 0):

When your website traffic is routed through the Cloudflare network, they act as a reverse proxy. As a result, when responding to requests and logging them, your origin server returns a  Cloudflare IP address.

You can log the original visitor IP address in Apache2 by enabling `mod_remoteip`.

1. Enable the module:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod remoteip
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
2. Edit your vhost config file. The default file is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. Between `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `</VirtualHost>`, add the following line:

   ```
   RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
   ```